# How would you analyse a file too big for memory?

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I was asked this question in a live coding interview round by the recruiter. I was not sure how to do this with code.

I thought of splitting the file into multiple files and then read those chunks through multiple threads.

But I was not able to implement the same.

Any help with the implementation or some other approach will be appreciated !

Comment: This is too broad - if I was asked this question in an interview, I'd ask "what kind of file, what kind of analysis?"

Comment: interview questions like this are absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would answer "It depends".  In an interview scenario, they're likely giving you a vague question intentionally to see where you go with it.  As others point out, finding out about the file, and what information you want to get out of it are key, and potential solutions could vary widely depending on these factors.

For example, if the file is in fact CSV, and you want to do potentially complex analysis on the data (sorts, counts, aggregations, etc), then pushing it into a relational database table, say H2, might not be a bad idea.  If the file contains more free-form text, you might want to index it with Lucene, or push it into an ElasticSearch index, and poke at it with Kibana.

None of these solutions are analyzing the file "with code" though, and would be completely ineffective if the file was, say, a 100GB movie clip.  Since they're asking how you would analyze the file "with code", I expect they're trying to see if you know how to do byte-oriented I/O (e.g. Java InputStream) vs character-oriented (e.g. Reader) and/or how to read through a potentially large  file using a buffer (i.e. without loading the whole file into memory).

Here's a simple code example...

```
import java.io.*;

public class StreamFile {
    /** Stream through a file using a buffer. */
    final static int BUFSIZE = 1024; // Use a 1K buffer.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(args[0])));
        long totalBytes = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            totalBytes += bis.read(buf, 0, BUFSIZE); // Do something here with the data in buf.
            System.out.println(totalBytes); // Show progress.
        }
        System.out.println("Read " + totalBytes + " bytes");
        bis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. I think you are spot on with `I expect they're trying to see if you know how to do byte-oriented I/O (e.g. Java InputStream) vs character-oriented (e.g. Reader) and/or how to read through a potentially large file using a buffer (i.e. without loading the whole file into memory).` I mean how can i do this  ? If at least you can point me to exact Keyword so that I can google or something ? What buffer ? I would be really thankful

Comment: I added a link to a code example.  I didn't do an exhaustive search to find the best one, but the general idea is to either read the file one byte at a time (until EOF), or up to a certain amount of bytes into a byte buffer (until EOF).  You can use a Reader if you know the file is characters, otherwise you need to use Steams.  The Java Tutorial, off of the Oracle site is petty good.  Otherwise, search for something like 'java buffer stream file' etc.

Comment: I think this article sums it up perfectly, insync with what you suggested. Would love to have your feedback on this short but crisp article. https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: Sure, the article is pretty good, but it has a couple of issues for your purposes.  First off, it demonstrates using 3rd party packages (i.e. Guava and Apache Commons), which could be OK if you're already using those packages, but may not help if you're trying to learn the underlying concept (i.e. how to read through a file using a buffer).  In addition, it brings dependency management, and potentially transient dependency management into the picture (i.e.  How do I get those jars, and potentially any jars those jars depend on, into my CLASSPATH).  It might be best to stick with the plain JDK.

Comment: Second (ran out of room in comment;), the plain Java example assumes that the file contains characters (not bytes that may or may not map to characters), and also that one line will fit into memory (ie. the file may be 100GB, and contain no newlines).

Comment: Yeah you are right. That makes perfect sense. I think I will have to dig in a bit more but i got the basic idea. Need to use `Input streams`  to read the data from the buffer in case the file doesn't contain characters, and reading byte by byte rather than loading the whole file in the memory.  Else go for `Buffered Reader ` if it contains characters. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate !

Comment: I tried a sample code for reading a 10GB file. If I am using a BufferedReader I am getting out of memory exception but on using BufferedInputStream its seems to work perfectly. Like you said, I read it else were also that if the file contains normal text we shiuld use BufferedReader. But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea ?

Comment: I replaced the example link with a small program that I hope demonstrates streaming concisely.  This should be able to stream through a really big file before overflowing the 'totalBytes' long.  It's hard to say why you're running out of memory using a Reader without seeing the code.  One common error would be if you are using readLine() on a binary file that has no lines in it, which could read the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the file type/contents, you could possibly load it into a database table and do analysis through queries on it there (if it was a .csv file for example).

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad topic but usually these types of problems are solved using buffer.

The size of the buffer is what your memory can hold and you can read data from file and load it in buffer to perform the task and then empty the buffer and load the next chunk and so on.

For example, if you want to sort some data which is too big for memory, we use method known as **external sorting**.

Mostly, relational database uses this external sort method sort the data when we use **order by** clause in our query. For deeper details on this, there is a wonderful lecture of which video link is pasted below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjFI9CJy6x0&t=3506s

I hope it helps you in understanding.

Comment: I am looking for java code for implementing this.

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402106/how-to-speed-up-external-merge-sort-in-java